# Accessing constants without always specifying the module

Tags: ruby

I have a module with several constants:

```
module My::Very::Long::Module::Name
  FIRST_CONSTANT = 1
  SECOND_CONSTANT = 2
  THIRD_CONSTANT = 3
  ...
end
```

Elsewhere, I want to build an array with some of those constants:

```
[My::Very::Long::Module::Name::FIRST_CONSTANT, My::Very::Long::Module::Name::SECOND_CONSTANT]
```

This is very annoying. Is there a better way, perhaps without always having to use the module name prefix?

Comment: Why not build this array in the module, where constants can be accessed by short name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create sort of alias

```
M = My::Very::Long::Module::Name
p [M::FIRST_CONSTANT, M::SECOND_CONSTANT]
```

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev By the way, what is the recipe of becoming Ruby Ninja like you (and few others who at SO have answers for all questions)?

Comment: Some advice from Jon Skeet himself: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/ :)

Comment: Cone, I see nothing wrong with #2. You've assigned the value to a constant (`M`), but it could be a variable.  As for #1, off with its head!

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I certainly was. Thanks  for pinging me :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve there. One possible solution is to build that array of yours closer to the constants. Check out this totally made up example:

```
module Postable
  FREE_POST_TYPES = ['text', 'image']
  PREMIUM_POST_TYPES = ['video']

  def types
    FREE_POST_TYPES + PREMIUM_POST_TYPES
  end
end

class Article
  extend Postable
end

Article.types # => ["text", "image", "video"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```
%i(FIRST_CONSTANT SECOND_CONSTANT).map { |c|
  My::Very::Long::Module::Name.const_get(c)
}
#=> [1, 2]
```